# 'Replicate function' not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to add leading zeros dynamically to month/date and below is my query:

```
select 
LEFT(CONCAT(isnull(replicate('0' ,2-len(convert(varchar,month('1/1/2018')))+ convert(varchar,day('1/1/2018'))),''),space(2)),2)
```

Expected output:

'01' for 1/1/2018 but I'm getting '00'.

Any help?!

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do here? Are you trying to get 2 digit days and months? Several things in here are less than ideal. varchar with no length, month function (you should use datepart instead).

Comment: Yeah, if the month is single digit, I want to add leading zero to it. So if month is '1' then i want to make '01'

Comment: Replicate is working fine. What you really should use is [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Just convert your date/datetime to varchar with the optional style that you want. But really that kind of thing should be done in the front end instead of the database.

Comment: You don't need `REPLICATE` for this, and I agree with all of Sean's comments, and will add that you should never use `m/d/y` (or is that `d/m/y`? see the problem?) Try `SELECT RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(GETDATE())), 2);` or just `SELECT CONVERT(char(5), GETDATE(), 101);` for `mm/dd`.

Answer (score 0):

I take it your date is a stored as a string to begin with.  You can convert it to a date, which will add the leading zeroes, then convert it to a varchar [with whatever format code you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Use 101 format to get what you are looking for:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,'1/2/2018'),101)
```

Output:

```
01/02/2018
```

As Aaron Bertrand commented, this format can be unclear about which value is day and which is month.